# cmake string without quotation marks and with quotation marks

Tags: cmake

I use the following CMake script to illustrate my question:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project (HelloWord)
# set variable
set(mylist "Hello "
            "the "
            "world!")
message("${mylist}")
message(${mylist})
```

Then we will find the following output in the screen:

```
Hello ;the ;world!
Hello the world!
```

My question is why there are difference between "${mylist}" and ${mylist}. Thanks.

EDIT:
 When I use the following code to get the length of "${mylist}", it always returns 0, but I think it should be 3.

list(LENGTH "${mylist}" mylen)
message(${mylen})

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${mylist}` is a list of three items which is rendered into a string if double-quoted. The string representation of a list happens to be exactly the same as CMake represents the list internally: the items separated by semicolons.

Without double-quotes, the list falls apart into arguments of the `message` command: instead of a single string `message` receives 3 arguments. And the `message` command handles multiple arguments in such a way that the arguments are simply printed one after another.

The correct syntax to get the length of the list is:

```
list(LENGTH mylist mylen)
```